# Is "risky" an acceptable spelling of "risqué"?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-word, spelling-pronunciations

Is "risky" an acceptable spelling of "risqué" or "risque" (suggestive of sexual impropriety), such as in [this article](http://www.inquisitr.com/2607911/selena-gomez-poses-braless-in-risky-photo-shoot-images/)?

> Selena Gomez has posed braless in a risky and sultry new photo-shoot
>   for the British magazine British InStyle’s December edition.

I looked at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/risky) and [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/risky), and they don't mention that meaning in their definitions of "risky". However, [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/218811/1420) states that the OED has it as a meaning of "risky".

Comment: I don't think so. I believe they meant risqué. Don't take me on my word though; I'm curious what comes out of this one. If it's in the OED, someone better provide proof!

Comment: A Google for "Bordering upon, suggestive of, what is morally objectionable or offensive" (with quotes) comes up with 2 results: the answer you link to and a quote from _Finnegans Wake_.

Comment: @MrLister I think you can discount *Finnegans Wake* as dispositive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Risky* is a fully Anglicized version of the French *risqué*. It's comparatively rare now<sup>†</sup>, but from the 1880s down to the end of WWII it was far more common to write of *risky* stories and jokes than of *risqué* ones.

[image: risky/risqué]
—[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=risky+stories%2Crisky+jokes%2Crisqu%C3%A9+stories%2Crisqu%C3%A9+jokes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crisky%20stories%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crisky%20jokes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crisqu%C3%A9%20stories%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crisqu%C3%A9%20jokes%3B%2Cc0)
(I do not include uses with *risque*, which outstrip all of these and really **are** mis-spellings.)

This was not mere journalistic illiteracy; here are a couple of quotations from unimpeachably literary figures:

> The diplomatist told me risky stories all through dinner so it was quite natural that this cheek should blush fiery red. —Somerset Maugham, *Lady Frederick*, 1907
>
> I was wild too, and I admit. I didn’t mind for anything, not even for his squeezing and pushing me on the stairs, or his risky jokes. —Joyce Cary, *Herself Remembered*, 1941

The first speaker is an aristocratic, the second a servant who has married into the respectable middle class and then abandoned it to become the model and mistress of the artist Gulley Jimson.

---

<sup>†</sup> But then so is *risqué*; in today's more relaxed climate we are far less titillated by the mere mention of unspecified impropriety than our Victorian, Edwardian and Georgian ancestors were.

Comment: It's not clear that Somerset Maugham used *risky stories* to suggest that the diplomatist was telling Lady Frederick salacious anecdotes (1911/12). She is retelling an episode where she had applied rouge (blusher) unevenly on her  cheeks, in an earlier line we read:  *“...I had a foreign diplomatist on my right side which bloomed like a rose, [her right cheek] and a bishop on my left which was white like the lily...”*  The diplomat's stories could have been episodes of danger, so L. Fredrick's right cheek reddened in response.

Comment: Whereas the bishop's stories were horrifying, so her left cheek looked drained in comparison *“...And as the Bishop whispered in my left ear harrowing details of distress in the East End, it was only decent that the other should exhibit a becoming pallor....”* Besides would a diplomat have retold saucy stories to an aristocrat at a formal dinner party?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The point of Lady F's story is that "by a merciful interposition of Providence" the sorts of stories she was being told on either hand were appropriate to her makeup. And, yes, in Edwardian England, in Lady F's set, it's quite likely that a sophisticated foreigner would tell that sort of story to a woman of Lady F's reputation. A "risky" story is one whose telling exposes one to risk, not one whose action involves danger and risk undergone; and stories of danger and risk would not conventionally elicit a "blush" but a "pallor"--as do the Bishop's harrowing tales.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But if you're still unconvinced, here’s an example from a much soberer genre: Havelock Ellis’ [*The Pyschology of Sex*, vol.II, Appendix B, History XVI](https://books.google.com/books?id=VrwRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA322&dq=%22risky+stories%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi13NnjmLTNAhWJ24MKHVmgBHAQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=risky&f=false): “This man’s mind was replete with all manner of risky stories, all sorts of sexual details.”

Comment: I don't know Maugham's play, but could it be that the author wanted to emphasise Lady Fredrick's shallowness and foolishness by writing *risky*. In the theatre,  would an actress have said, *ris-KEE* or *ris-KAY*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA On the contrary: Lady F is doing her damnedest to discourage her very young suitor by demonstrating her hardened and artificial sophistication.

Answer (score 7):

The journalist misspelled *risqué*

> Selena Gomez has posed braless in a **risky** [and sultry] new photo-shoot...

The same celebrity news is reported in *[Highsnobiety](http://www.highsnobiety.com/2015/09/09/selena-gomez-revival-album-artwork/)*, but there risquè is written correctly.

> Selena Gomez Strips Down for **Risqué** Album Artwork

Looking on the Internet, I found no reputable website that suggested *risky* is a spelling variant of *risqué*: the two terms mean two different things, and have two different pronunciations.

[**grammar.about**](http://grammar.about.com/od/alightersideofwriting/a/Risky-And-Risqu-E.htm)

> The adjective risky (pronounced **ris-kee**) means dangerous or hazardous. The adjective risqué (pronounced **ris-kay**) means sexually daring, suggestive, or indecent.
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. Much to the concern of their parents, most children enjoy **risky** play involving great speed and heights.
> 2. Despite her rather **risqué** outfit, Kathryn was really a rather quiet and conventional woman.

**[grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/risky-vs-risque/)** (unfortunately, it's become infested with sponsored ads)

> **Risky vs risqué**
>
> **Risky** means containing the possibility or likeliness of danger or failure. *Risky* is an adjective, related adjectives are *riskier* and *riskiest*. The adverb form is *riskily*, the noun form is *riskiness*. *Risky* appears around 1825, taking the place of *riskful*.
>
> **Risqué** means improper, borderline indecent. *Risqué* is an adjective, it appears in the English language in the 1860s, borrowed from the French *risqué*, past participle of *risquer*, meaning tending toward impropriety. *Risky* and *risqué* are pronounced differently, *risky* is pronounced RISkee, and *risqué* holds on to its French pronunciation, risKAY.

[**Paul Brians' *Common Errors in English Usage***](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/risky.html)

> **RISKY/RISQUÉ**
>
> People unfamiliar with the French-derived word “risqué” (‘slightly indecent”) often write “risky” by mistake. Bungee-jumping is risky, but nude bungee-jumping is risqué.

**[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/risque)**

> **risqué** adjective
>   1. daringly close to indelicacy or impropriety; off-color:
>   *a risqué story.*
>
> **Can be confused**
>   *risky*, *risqué*.

---

**An Explanation for this spelling error**

There used to be a time when editors hired  proofreaders and copy editors to weed out spelling and punctuation errors (etc.) before an article graced the pages of a magazine or newspaper.

But nowadays, writers and journalists, for financial reasons and laziness, are increasingly reliant on spell-checkers. The adjective *risky* which appears in *[Inquisitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisitr)* is not spelt (spelled) wrong, and that is probably why it was allowed to pass through. Nobody had spotted the error.

One of EL&U's most esteemed contributors, Sven Yargs, is a freelance copy-editor and has mentioned this problem several times.

[Is “make due” now considered acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/231267/44619)

> 1. **What happens when you spell "make do" as "make due" in an online article?** If you notice it later, or if someone points it out to you, and you don't like the idea that some percentage of your readers will think that you don't know how to spell "make do" correctly, you simply go back into the article and change the spelling. No permanent harm, no foul. And let's face it: It's quite a luxury to keep a bunch of editors and proofreaders on staff just to intercept those types of problems preemptively. That's why, in the past couple of decades, copy editors and proofreaders have become the whooping cranes and California condors of the publishing industry.

[Is it “chalk it up to” or “chock it up to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/294239/44619)

> 2. A Google Books search finds more than 40 unique matches for "chock it up to" in which the author presumably meant to say "chalk it up to" but either spelled chalk wrong or didn't know the correct traditional spelling of the idiom. Tellingly, the vast majority of these 40+ instances come from the past ten years, **suggesting either that *chock* is emerging as a legitimate variant spelling of *chalk* in this situation or that many publishers no longer employ copy editors to find and correct mistakes of this type.**

Comment: Always a problem, but in this case I don't think so.  If the writer chose the wrong word the sentence becomes "risqué and sultry".  The meanings can be too close to each other to have a combined impact. I'll admit that "risky and sultry" doesn't have much impact either.

Comment: @Icy What is "risky" about a photoshoot? But the young singer/actress has posed topless (risquè) in the photo session and I gather she is something of a teen idol. So, that is probably why the reporter picked up on it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA perhaps they're hinting at/confused by the risk of accidentally revealing more than planned. Or the sub-editor was and so missed the typo

Comment: @Mari-LouA A risqué photoshoot might be risky for an entertainer who relied on Disney to make her career.  On the other hand, Miley Cyrus.

Answer (score 5):

No. *Risky* and *risqué* do not have the same meaning.

Something that is *risky* is dangerous, or prone to loss. "Investing in junk bonds can be lucrative, but is risky."

Something that is *risqué* is in questionable taste, especially in a sexual way. "She wore a dress that was a little risqué for the office party."

Comment: I already described what risqué meant in the question.

Comment: Yeah well, risky doesn't mean that.

Comment: Do you have any authority aside from your own for this pronouncement? The original question lists evidence pointing both ways, which you don't address: if *risky* cannot mean the same thing as *risqué,* why is it used this way in the linked *Inquisitr* article? Why is it listed as a possible meaning in the Oxford English Dictionary? If what you really mean is that you don't think people *should* use these words with the same meaning, why shouldn't they? Or if what you mean is that people generally don't use it with this meaning, even though some people do, provide evidence for this.

Comment: The Oxford definition for *risky* has, at number two, *risqué* without comment.

Answer (score 1):

[risqué](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/risqu%C3%A9) in the English sense of naughty, sexy, salacious seems to translate to the French *scabreux* ([among many others](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/reverse/risqu%C3%A9))

[Wicktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/risqu%C3%A9) notes that risk and *risqué* share the same French root *risquer* - to risk - although it notes that the English use is a 
[borrowing or loanword](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#loanword) from French.

Might your quote be playing it straight in saying the photo might in fact be **risky** to her cultivated image or perhaps her career?

Comment: If it was a risk to her, they'd say "sultry *but* risky" rather than an and, as they'd be contrasting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OED does give the definition "risqué" for the word *risky*, with an example from

> 2004   C. Bazalgette in M. Bonham *Casino* p. xi,   She loved to show off and to tell risky stories.

It seems the story is using *risky* with this meaning.

Comment: I suspect a misspelling. The two words are quite distinct. See Mari-Lou A's definitive answer above.

Answer (score 1):

There is little doubt as to the word's etymology:

> Compare French *risqué* fraught with risk (probably 1690), improper, unsuitable, shocking (1839 or earlier), use as adjective of past participle of risquer risk v. In sense 3 after either risqué adj. or its etymon French risqué.

**Risky** was the first of the pair to be recorded in English.

OED

> **risky**, adj.
>
> 1. **Involving the possibility of injury, loss, or other adverse or unwelcome circumstance; dangerous; hazardous; fraught with risk.**
>
> 1813   R. Mayo View Anc. Geogr. & Anc. Hist. iii. vii. 59   The Tudors were equal to the occasion, and, trading on the desire of both sides for friendship, did not commit themselves to any expensive or risky policy.

On the other hand "risqué", in its primary meaning, did not appear for a further 50-odd years, and follows a Victorian tradition (that still continues) of using the French word for anything sexual.

> **risqué**, adj.
>
> Origin: A borrowing from French. Etymon: French risqué.
>
> Etymology: < French risqué (see risky adj.). Compare risky adj.
>
> **Slightly indecent and liable to shock, esp. by being sexually suggestive.** Cf. risky adj. 3.
>
> 1867   ‘Ouida’ Under Two Flags II. iv. 121   *She..sang..the most wicked and risqué of her slang songs.*

Going back to "risky" = "risqué" (as per the sense 3 of "risky" mentioned above) the first example is interesting:

> 1881   Daily News 25 July 2/6   He has carefully eliminated all the risky Gallicisms to which..the Palais Royal artists gave such point.

This example is self-referential - of course, it should be "all the **risqué** Gallicisms" but the writer has eliminated them.

The examples that follow do nothing to dispel the idea of "eliminating Gallicisms"

> 1920   D. H. Lawrence Women in Love xxix. 484   Loerke was everywhere at once, like a gnome, suggesting drinks for the women, making an obscure, slightly risky joke with the men, confusing and mystifying the waiter.
>
> 1974   Times 7 June 18/6   Those who slept missed some risky jokes.
>
> 2004   C. Bazalgette in M. Bonham Casino p. xi   She loved to show off and to tell risky stories.

The OED states what has been done. It does not necessarily approve.

So, to answer the question,

> Is "risky" an acceptable spelling of "risqué" or "risque"?

It depends on what you mean by "acceptable." I would say "No, it isn't as it could give rise to misunderstandings as the two words are distinct in their primary meaning. Let's keep them distinct."

Answer (score 0):

> People unfamiliar with the French-derived word “risqué” (‘slightly 
>   indecent”) often write “risky” by mistake. Bungee-jumping is *risky,*
>   but nude bungee-jumping is *risqué.* (Paul Brians, [*Common Errors in English Usage*](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/risky.html))

The article you cite blurs the line between this use, and the use of *risky* as dangerous.

Comment: I would classify nude bungee-jumping as _extremely_ risky.

Comment: @Gandalf only if a harness counts as clothing.

Comment: You should cite the source of the quick quip. It comes from Paul Brian's website http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/risky.html